# KeyError when deploying Python Function App on Azure

Tags: python-3.x, azure, keyerror, python-wheel, azure-function-app

I'm new to azure and I'm getting this KeyError when deploying my python function on Azure portal, not sure what is the reason.

I have added just one package, "tweepy == 3.8.0" in my requirements.txt and it seems like it is crashing mostly right during it's installation during deployment, And the PySocks package is probably just a dependency for tweepy package.

I have no such issues when the debug it locally. The function runs absolutely fine locally.

How can I resolve this deployment issue?

Error:

```
There was an error restoring dependencies. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anjan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\anjan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\anjan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\tools\python\packapp\__main__.py", line
234, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\anjan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\tools\python\packapp\__main__.py", line
60, in main
    find_and_build_deps(args)
  File "C:\Users\anjan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\tools\python\packapp\__main__.py", line
142, in find_and_build_deps
    wheel.install(paths, maker)
  File "C:\Users\anjan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\tools\python\packapp\distlib\wheel.py",
line 519, in install
    row = records[u_arcname]
KeyError: 'PySocks-1.7.0.dist-info/'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"func: pack" task has been a common problem for users. I could solve it by trying a preview feature that is meant to address this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/wiki/Server-Side-Build